# Fibonacci string array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, string

I have an array: A B AB BAB ABBAB BABABBAB ... The number of each term of the array is base on the Fibonacci number.Put the n-th string and the n+1-th string together, then producing the n+2-th string,eg.BABABBAB = BAB + ABBAB.
Then is the 10^16-th letter is A or B?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to write a program to tell you this?

Comment: Tagged as homework, because I assume it is. Nobody will do your homework for you, because you need to learn, but if you are more specific about where you are stuck then we will give you hints.

Comment: sounds like homework... what have you tried till now? whats the problem with your solution?

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: I love the combination of your comment and your user name. Freakin' hilarious.

Comment: It's A B. ...But if it isn't A B, it should certainly B A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `f[n]` be the `n`th [fibonacci number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).

Assume we want to find the value at position `x` in the string obtained by concatenating `f[1], f[2], ..., f[n]`.

1. Find the lowest `k` such that `f[1] + f[2] + ... + f[k] >= x`. So position `x` belongs to word that has `f[k]` characters (at least in the concatenation it does. But since all words are made up from `a` and `b`, we'll try to reduce the problem to just those two).
2. To find the position corresponding to `x` in the term `f[k]`, subtract `f[1] + ... + f[k - 1]` from `x`.
3. if `k = 1` print `a`, if `k = 2` print `b`, else go to step 4.
4. 1. if `f[k - 2] < x`, then the position we're looking for is in the word corresponding to (with length) `f[k - 1]`. Subtract 1 from `k` and `f[k - 2]` from `x` and go to **step 3**.
   2. Else, the position we're looking for is in the word corresponding to `f[k - 2]`. Subtract 2 from `k`, leave `x` unchanged and go to **step 3**.

This doesn't require generating the actual words, just their lengths, which are the basic fibonacci numbers.

**Worked example**
- note that I'm only using the actual words for illustration purposes, they are not needed.

```
n  f[n]  corresponding word
1  1     a
2  1     b
3  2     ab
4  3     bab
5  5     abbab 
6  8     bababbab
```

Concatenating all these we get: `ababbababbabbababbab`. Let's ask ourselves what's at position `10` (it's `b`).

```
1. f[1] + f[2] + f[3] + f[4] + f[5] >= 10, so k = 5
2. x = 10, f[1] + f[2] + f[3] + f[4] = 7, so subtract 7 from x, giving x = 3
3'. k isn't 1 or 2, skip this.
4'. f[k - 2 = 3] = 2 < x. k = 4, x = 1
3''. still ignoring this.
4'' f[k - 2 = 2] = 1 >= x. k = 2, x = 1
3'''. k = 2, print 'b'.
```

Comment: Definition of Fibonacci numbers: `f[1] = 1, f[2] = 1, f[n] = f[n-1] + f[n-2]`. If you remember the previous values, you can calculate the next very quickly. Don't try to do this with recursion.

Comment: This may be handy: `f[1]+f[2]+...+f[n]=f[n+2]-1`

Answer (score 2):

please don't take this answer too serious:

i never was good and math and this sounds like this task should be too heavy to calculate without a freaky algorithm, so my solution would be to simply have a guess. to choose between `A` and `B`, i would write a very simple programm like this in php to print out the first 15 or 20 "lines":

```
<?php
$var1 = "B";
$var2 = "A";
for($i=3;$i<=15;$i++){
    $tmp = $var2;
    $var2 = $var1;
    $var1 = $tmp.$var1;
    echo $i." ".$var1."<br>";
}
echo strlen(implode('',explode('B',$var1)));
echo "<br>";
echo strlen(implode('',explode('A',$var1)));
?>
```

the result shows there are always less `A`s (38%) than `B`s (62%) - so the chance to be right when guessing `B` aren't that bad.

Comment: Nice! +1. So far this is the best question of the day.

Comment: This answer's worth the comment that the n'th string is of length f[n] and contains f[n-1] B's and f[n-2] A's, so the proportion of B's is (sqrt(5)-1)/2. That 62% estimate isn't bad at all :)

Comment: Thanks for your inspiring works!I always ignored the solution of probability theory.