# Fibonacci string array revised

Tags: arrays, algorithm, fibonacci

Maybe I misunderstand my assignment last time.The actually problem description should be like the following:

I have an array: `A B AB BAB ABBAB BABABBAB`

The number of each term of the array is base on the Fibonacci number.

Put the n-th string and the n+1-th string together, then producing the n+2-th string:

`BABABBAB = BAB + ABBAB`

Then is the x-th (eg.10^16-th) letter of the n-th term which count from the last letter is A or B? Eg. the 6th letter was B, not only in the 6th term `BABABBAB` but also in the later terms `ABBABBABABBAB`

The 7th letter is A in the the 6th term `BABABBAB` and also in the later terms - `ABBABBABABBAB`

The most inspiring news is that someone has a Θ(1) solution.

> if [x / g] * g >= x - 1 then it's B
>   else it's A.
>   g is the golden mean.

but he or she didn't explain why it works.

Comment: I just thought that: if x > f(n) and x < f(n+1), that means x is among the f(n+1) and it's the x - f(n-1) in the f(n-2) then just going on until to the 1st or 2nd term.But the complexity will be Θ(n). The solution I added was so simple and perfect to solve the problem, but I can't figure out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fibonacci string array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353107/fibonacci-string-array)

Comment: You should update your original question with the new information, rather than starting a new question on the same topic.

Comment: @Paul R: It's a different problem from the previous one,though they have same assumptions.

Comment: Can you post a link to where you got that from? I don't think it works. `[6 / g] * g = 4.8`, which is not at least `5`. So you would say it's A when in fact it's B.

Comment: @IVlad @Paul R @Brian Roach  Thanks for your attention! It's all my fault to misunderstand much information.I found the original problem. http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=230

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Wikipedia article on Fibonacci Word. A formula for the n'th digit is given there along with references.

Comment: +1: The problem gives the reverse of Fibonacci words. Can prove using induction...